# Got "-std=c++11: command not found" error when trying to compile a object file using g++

Tags: c++, linux, bash, variables, gcc

As in the title, when I try to compile an object file using g++ by running this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
name=textsweeper
srcdir=src
buildir=build
cc=g++
cppflags=-Wall -std=c++11 -ggdb -O
libs=
rm -f $buildir/$name $buildir/main.o
$cc $cppflags $srcdir/main.cpp -c -o $buildir/main.o
$cc $buildir/main.o $libs -o $buildir/$name
```

I get the following error:

```
$ bash compile
compile: line 6: -std=c++11: command not found
```

And other errors about things being only available only with stdc++11.
I've tried yahooing the error, but I've only got answers to about errors about actual command not arguments.

Comment: By the way, consider using something like GNU Make.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've tried it, but I think Makefiles are overcomplicated.

Comment: Not nearly as overcomplicated as this shell script will be after a very small number of additions to your project.

Comment: @digitcrusher Yes, they are overcomplicated for non-trivial projects. The same thing will be true for your bash script in a little while. You do not want to write such files manually. You want to generate them automatically. Have a look at [CMake](https://cmake.org) for a build system that’s widely used in the C++ world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variable assignment is space sensitive. Change:

```
cppflags=-Wall -std=c++11 -ggdb -O
```

to

```
cppflags="-Wall -std=c++11 -ggdb -O"
```

Otherwise, you're trying to run the command `-std=c++11 -ggdb -O` with the environment including a setting of `cppflags=-Wall`. bash allows temporary environment settings to be done this way, which is why its important to quote any variable assignments that contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer.
Now when i run the script no "-std=c++" errors are showing up in my console.

Comment: To the OP: You *should* have been able to work out that this was the problem.  This line was clearly marked as the problem, and the error message told you that bash was trying to run `-std=c++11` as a comand.

Comment: @MartinBonner That assumes you know that commands can be preceded by variables assignments.  Otherwise, it's probably not obvious why the shell would think `std=c++11` is the name of a command to run.

Comment: @chepner: Yeah, I don't blame the OP for not knowing about that. I was using bash for half a decade before I learned about that behavior (previously, I'd always just `export`ed names before running subcommands that relied on them). Just because it's obvious to me now doesn't mean it's a simple problem.

Comment: @chepner No, actually I didn't assume that the op knew commands can be preceded by assignments.  I just assumed he could see that the assignment is being split at the first space - so he needs to quote the assignment.